# Java Extracting the values from a list and include it as column names in a sql query

Tags: java, performance, jdbc

I have a function hasColumnBeenIdentified() which takes an arraylist()(columnNameList) as one of the arguments to this method. The logic the method performs is that the method has to connect to the database and execute a Query. The Query that it executes is a select query in which the column names will be retrieved from the arraylist which is passed as an argument to this method. The Query will look like below

```
 String query = "Select columnNameList FROM "+ currTableName + " " + 
                "WHERE ROWNUM <= " + numberOfSamplesForInstaceMatching;
```

I have two issues here.

1. how to extract the values from the list(columnNameList) and use it in the query and execute the query. I.e the ColumnNameList contains the list of columns whose values needs to be retrieved from the db.  I need to know how to insert the columnnames in the query.
2. After executing the above query, once we get the result set, I would like to know how to extract the column values from the resultset and store it in a hashmap.

Note: The method hasColumnBeenIdentified() will get invoked multiple times i.e it will get invoked based on the number of tables in a particular schema. Hence I cannot customize the resultset nor the columnNamelist, since for each table, the number of columns will be vary.

Any help on this is much appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: that 'ColumnNameList', is it arraylist of strings?

Comment: Yes its an ArrayList<String>

Comment: What is the method signature and return value for this function? You mention that you want to store the query results in a HashMap, but you also name your method as hasColumnBeenIdentified (which suggests you want to return a boolean and would imply you don't need the HashMap at all).

Comment: how is the structure of your final hashmap ? is it similar to HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>finalValuesMap=new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>() ?

Comment: Thanks for the response Fathah, yes the final hashmap will look like HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>finalValuesMap=new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a String with the columnnames from the list and use this string in the query. E.g. you can use following:

```
String columnsString  = org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join(ColumnNameList, ",");
String query = "Select ColumnNameList FROM "+ currTableName + " " + 
            "WHERE columnName IN ( " + columnsString + ")";
```

Another possibility withou using a external library is to create the string in a for-loop:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append(list.remove(0));

for( String s : ColumnNameList) {
    builder.append(", ");
    builder.append(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my Understand you need to coombine your column name list in query.For this you can iterate your list create comma separated string of your column name.

```
String columnStr = "";
for(String columnName : yourList<>)  
{  
   columnStr += columnName+",";  
}  
columnStr = columnStr.substring(0, columnStr.length()-1);
```

Replace this string in your query.

```
String query = "Select "+columnStr+" FROM "+ currTableName + " " + 
            "WHERE ROWNUM <= " + numberOfSamplesForInstaceMatching;
```

For getting column name back from `ResultSet` you need `ResultSetMetaData` like given below.

```
ResultSet rs = ...; //Your ResultSet
ResultSetMetaData rsm = rs.getMetaData();
String columnName = rsm.getColumnName("YourColumnIndex"); //Index start from 1
```

For storing your result in HashMap you first need to decide howto store it into HashMap.

Edit :
You may use external library to join your list into String, one of them is
[Apache's commons lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Iterable,%20char%29)

Like this : `String columnNames = StringUtils.join(YOUR_LIST,",");`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Yagnesh.I tried the above and the columnStr returns a null value in the begining followed by the firstcolumn name. For storing the result in the hashmap,  I will store the columnnames which was obtained from the myList as the key and the values will be from theresultset obtained after the execution of the query.I,e the values corresponding to each column will be stored as values in the hashmap.

Comment: The final hashmap will look something like this HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>finalValuesMap=new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>()

Comment: What is the key value for your HashMap is it your column name ?

Comment: Key will be the Column name and value will be the list of values fetched from the database

Comment: for multiple row there will each entry for each column which contain list to value for that column of all rows as hashmap value right ?